# Do domains typically have to be declared in bankruptcy proceedings?

Tags: bankruptcy, domain-name

I've been trying to research this, and so far all I've found is a lot of academic legal essays concluding the law hasn't really caught up to the technology.

Do domains typically need to be declared when filing for bankruptcy? I'm not talking about domains worth thousands of dollars or anything, just an obscure domain worth the $10 or so that was paid to register it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's better asked at https://money.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @BlueDogRanch Money SE [states](https://stackexchange.com/sites) that it is "*for people who want to be financially literate*". By contrast, the OP's question pertains to *legal obligations* in bankruptcy proceedings.

Answer (score 4):

> Do domains typically need to be declared when filing for bankruptcy?

Yes. Concealment of registered domains may be grounds for denial of discharge. See [*In re Money Centers of America, Inc.*, (U.S. Bankruptcy Cort, July, 2019)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/inbco20190711655) ("*the registration of the domain name is an ownership interest that should have been disclosed*"). See also [*In re Luby*, 438 B.R. 817, 829-830 (2010)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/inbco20101001985):

> courts generally hold that domain names are subject to the same laws
> as other types of intangible property [...] And as such, it must be
> reported on a debtor's bankruptcy schedules.

(citations omitted).

The *Luby* opinion reflects that materiality of a domain is more relevant than the cost of registering it.